# solve Z of matrix

Tags: matrix, homework

x=Cz+(lambda)z

x and z are n*1 column vectors
C is n*n matrix
(lambda) is a scalar

it want to solve for z. 
the hint is z=Iz where I is n*n
also C+(lambda) is an invalid expression, but C+(lambda)I is valid.
please help.

Comment: Think about how you can interpret scalar multiplication as a matrix operation. This is not really about using mathematica in the end, is it? [I guess that n at least is given? Do you have numerical or symbolic values? A bit more of information would be nice]

Comment: .... and remembering (or reading) how Eigenvalues/vectors are calculated is also helpful ;-)

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 2):

Without using **any** linear algebra knowledge:

```
SeedRandom[42];
n = 3;
c = RandomReal[{0, 1}, n {1, 1}];
x = RandomReal[{0, 1}, n];
zV = Array[z, n];
lambda = RandomReal[{0, 1}];
Solve[Thread[x == c.zV + lambda zV], zV]
(*
 {{z[1] -> 0.657591, z[2] -> 0.15559, z[3] -> 0.272442}}
*)
```

or perhaps you want

```
Solve[Thread[x == (c + lambda IdentityMatrix[n] ).zV], zV]
(* {{z[1] -> 0.805462, z[2] -> -0.158782, z[3] -> 0.330235}} *)
```

Which is equivalent for example to:

```
LinearSolve[c + IdentityMatrix[3] lambda, x]
```

Comment: thank you. I've start inputting this and worked. now I finish my homework.